# Change elements' CSS class on the fly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

On a page using jQuery, if I want to to change all classes from

```
col-lg-3 form-group
```

to

```
col-lg-8 form-group
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.col-lg-3.form-group').toggleClass('col-lg-3 col-lg-8');
```

`.toggleClass` just toggles the classnames based off the list given.

So if you run it again it will be back to the original.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from Tuvia's and jlemm45's answers, you can do:

```
$('.col-lg-3.form-group').switchClass( "col-lg-3", "col-lg-8", 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `removeClass()` and `addClass()`. The below code will search for elements which have **both** `.col-lg-3` and `.form-group` as class , and it will **remove** the `col-lg-3` class for those elements and **add** `col-lg-8` class.

```
$('.col-lg-3.form-group').removeClass('col-lg-3').addClass('col-lg-8');
```

**[Sample Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/4q6bt27t/)**

```js
$( ".form-group.col-lg-3" ).removeClass( "col-lg-3").addClass('col-lg-8');
```

```css
.form-group {
    color: blue;
  }
  .col-lg-3 {
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
  .col-lg-8{
font-size:50px;  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3 class="form-group col-lg-3">text</h3>
<h3 class="form-group">text</h3>
<h3 class="col-lg-3">text</h3>
<h3 class="form-group col-lg-3">text</h3>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple way to do it would be like below..

`$('.col-lg-3.form-group').removeClass('col-lg-3').addClass('col-lg-8')`

Removes the `col-lg-3` class and adds `col-lg-8`  to all the elements which has the combinations of both the classes `col-lg-3`  and `form-group` in its class attribute.

Comment: Depending on the scenario, this way could be preferred to `.switchClass` or `.toggleClass`  anwers, since it can't *accidentally* happen the other way around. **Being the question stated as it is, I'd choose this answer.** I think verbosity (and a bit of performance) for the sake of a gain in legibility and safety (disambiguation) is a **good trade-off**.

Comment: Yes being the question stated as it is, this is the best way..  toggleClass and switchClass will not even work for the second time here in given scenario which is against its usage purpose.... I prefer them to be used when actually toggling and switching back and forth .. I don't think that is necessary here.. So I keep it simple

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways but here is what I would do.

```
$('.form-group').removeClass('col-lg-3').addClass('col-lg-8');
```

Comment: this would add `col-lg-8` to `.form-group`s that do not have the `col-lg-3` class.